# Deleting a row in UITableView based on button present in header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a `UITableView` which I am creating by using custom `UITableViewCell`. The tableview shows some data populated from an array. Now I am using 2 image to highlight/unhighlight based on selection. [By default when application opens I am showing the first row with highlighted image without any selection].

The `UITableView` header contains one delete button now if I press delete button first time it happens succesfully.

```
-(IBAction)delete{
    [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [tableview reloadData];
}
```

Now as tableview get refreshed, all row contains unhighlighted image. Now as I select 3rd row and press header delete button how should I get the index number to be deleted.

I know about `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but is there any way which I put in IBAction method to get the selected cell index number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an ivar or property that holds the value of the latest selection. In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, have this line:

```
self.rowSelected = indexPath.row;
```

where rowSelected is a property. Then in your IBAction for the button, you can access that property:

```
-(IBAction)delete{
    if (self.rowSelected != -1){
        [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:self.rowSelected];
        [tableview reloadData];
        self.rowSelected = -1;
}
```

In the viewDidLoad method you should set the value of that property to 0 since you want the first row selected at start up.

Comment: But once the default highlighted row is deleted.Tableview get refreshed & Now all the row are unhighlighted, so i want to restrict the delete operation until it is not selected.

Comment: @SimFox, I'm not sure I understand your comment, but I added some code to my answer, so that after you delete, the rowSelected is set to -1, so that nothing will be deleted if the button is pushed again before selecting another row.

Answer (score 0):

In your .h file take an instance variable `NSInteger selectedRow`.

In you `init` or `viewDidLoad`, set default selection...

```
selectedRow=0;
```

Then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` do the following...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath
{
    selectedRow=indexPath.row;
}
```

Make a minor change in your delete method

```
-(IBAction)delete{
    if(selectedRow!=-1)
    {
       [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:selcetedRow];
       [tableview reloadData];
       selectedRow=-1;     //-1 to mark that no row has been selected now
    }
}
```

And you are done!!

Comment: But once the default highlighted row is deleted.Tableview get refreshed & Now all the row are unhighlighted, so i want to restrict the delete operation until it is not selected.

Comment: In your delete method, you can assign selectedRow=-1 to mark that no row has been selected now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexPathForSelectedRow` to determine which row is currently selected.  Change your delete method to:

```
-(IBAction)delete {
    NSIndexPath *selectedRow = [tableview indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (selectedRow) {
        [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:selectedRow.row];
        [tableview reloadData];
    }
}
```

Note that you will have to select the first row by default:

```
[tableview selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```